# Modal button only working for every other row, what is making it not work for every row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

HTML code:

```
      <html>
             <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablestyle.css">
        </head>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="datasource/people.json"> </script>

            <script>

            $(function() {

  var people = [];

   $.getJSON('datasource/people.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><button class='button-border   toggleModal'><span class='icon'></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>" + "  <td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + " </td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

                     $('.toggleModal').on('click', function (e) {
                       $('.modal').toggleClass('active');

                    });
                     });

                });

              });
           </script>

             <body>
        <table id="userdata" rules="groups" style="border: 1px solid             black;">
<thead>

    <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th>EmployeeNum</th>
                    <th>EmployeeName</th>
                    <th>ChargeNum</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>

    <tbody>



    </tbody>



          </table>
          <div class="modal">

<header>
  <button class="close toggleModal">Close</button>
        </header>

        <section>
  <p>To approve the timesheet and submit it to WAM press "Approve", to decline the timesheet for later viewing press "Disapprove"</p>
       </section>

         <button class="button-border button-success toggleModal">
            <span class="icon"></span> Approve </button>

          <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal">
                <span class="icon">< </span> Disapprove </button>
                       <!-- <script> $(docuemnt).ready(function(){ -->
                           <!-- var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#a').index() + 1; -->
                    <!-- $("#a").style.color = "red"}); -->
                    <!-- </script> -->

           </div>


            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>


          </body>
          </html>
```

CSS code:

```
    html{
        font:0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
        color:#333;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding:1em;
    }

    /* Tables */
 table{
width:100%;
        margin-bottom:1em;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px;
    }
  th{
font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#ddd;
    }

  td{
padding:0.5em;
        border:1px solid black;

    }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ddd;

}

  a.button {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;

text-decoration: none;
color: initial;
 }      

  @font-face {
 font-family: 'ios7-icon';
  src: url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.woff") format("woff"), url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.ttf") format("ttf");
font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
  }
   *, *:before, *:after {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
     }

   body {
padding: 50px;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' !important;
 font-weight: 300;
       }

     .wrapper {
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
            }

     h1 {
   font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 45px;
 color: #007aff;
        }

    h2 {
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 21px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
     }

       section {
 margin-top: 30px;
    }
    section p {
line-height: 1.4;
margin-bottom: 20px;
      }



   button {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: LightBlue; 
color: #007aff;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 14px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 /* &:nth-child(even){ */
  /* background: white; */
 /* } */
 /*  &:last-child {
     border-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 0;
   }*/
 }
 button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  button.button-border {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
  button.button-border:hover { 
  background: #007aff; 
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-decoration: none; 
 } 
button.button-success { 
 /color: #4dd865; */
  border-color: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-success:hover { 
   background: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-error { 
  color: #ff3b30; 
  border-color: #ff3b30; 
 } 
button.button-error:hover { 
  background: #ff3b30; 
 } 

.modal {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 430px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
 margin-top: -150px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   }
   .modal.active {
  display: block;
    }
.modal header {
 position: relative;
}
.modal h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .close {
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pull-right {
 float: right;
}

.icon {
 display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
   font-family: circle;
   margin-right: 5px;
   color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -moz-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -ms-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -o-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
   }
```

Json code that brings in table data:

```
{
    "person": [
    {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Kent",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 20,
       "hours":10
   },
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Wayne",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30,
       "hours":20
   }
   ]
  }
```

What happens is that the button that I am using at the beginning of the row will only work for every other row. The button essentially will allow the person to accept or decline the data within a given row, so the button will be needed for every row. The table must be dynamic in order to read in information from a source other than the local HTML page. If I were to add 3 table rows only two out of the three buttons will work, and even then sometimes the modal view will stop working. For instance, once the button is pressed a modal view comes up with two other buttons and as of right now if you click either of those buttons the view will close. But when adding more rows, when clicking the button in the initial row, the buttons that are in the modal view(that appear after you click the button inside the table row) do not work. And this is on top of the initial button only working for every other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you add the handler after adding all the rows ?

```
$(function() {
  var people = [];

  $.getJSON('datasource/people.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><button class='button-border   toggleModal'><span class='icon'></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>" + "  <td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + " </td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });

    // Add the click handler after adding all table rows
    $('#userdata').on('click', '.toggleModal', function (e) {
      $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

Otherwise, you are adding the handler once on the first row, twice on the second row, three times on the third row, etc.

And that is why it works on every other row.  Toggling twice (or any number divisible by 2) will cause it to toggle on and then off.

Also, your `<tbody>` is strangely place (inside of your thead).

Comment: Oops, I accidentally uploaded an older version of my code. I have edited and made the changes that you suggested but I still have the same issue.

Comment: My apologize you were right, I made a small syntax error. Thank you very much for the quick reply.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad it helped.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered so that others know you have found what you are looking for.

Comment: I am quite new to HTML, CSS, etc. Is there a place you recommend for learning, or any pointers regarding these languages?

Comment: Hmm.  Nothing in particular: I just learnt by doing.  There are some resources like edx, codecademy, khanacademy, thenewboston, etc.  But I have never used any of them.