# Collapsible JS element only working in every other row

Tags: javascript, css, netsuite

Putting these elements in a NetSuite Saved Search, however it will only function in every other row. [NetSuite Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEmAP.png) Any idea how to remedy this? From reading on other posts it seems like it could be either a row height issue or that every other one makes the JS code toggle twice on even rows. I am still learning JS so not sure how that functions.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuUaK.png)

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">TAL Drop Info</button>
<div class="content">
  <span class="gsub">FIRST NAME:</span><br> '||{contactprimary.firstname}||'
</div>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">TAL Drop Info</button>
<div class="content">
  <span class="gsub">FIRST NAME:</span><br> '||{contactprimary.firstname}||'
</div>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">TAL Drop Info</button>
<div class="content">
  <span class="gsub">FIRST NAME:</span><br> '||{contactprimary.firstname}||'
</div>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">TAL Drop Info</button>
<div class="content">
  <span class="gsub">FIRST NAME:</span><br> '||{contactprimary.firstname}||'
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code in a snippet (via the `<>` button in the toolbar), which is the preferred way of sharing your issue on this site. You can see it works fine. However what is needed here is the rendered output of your html - paste that into this snippet and let us take a look at that

Comment: Thank you for your help on the formatting, still new to coding and stack overflow. I am a bit confused what you mean by rendered output. The caveat of this is that its being added to a formula field in a query in NetSuite ERP. The collapse works on every other row of data but will not toggle on the middle ones. I think it may be specific to the ERP as the HTML CSS and JS work find in other environments. I am curious if its something similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239706/modal-button-only-working-for-every-other-row-what-is-making-it-not-work-for-ev

Comment: What I mean by rendered output is to view source and copy the HTML of the page you are showing in your screenshot. We just need the part that pertains to your question. Then, edit your question and edit the snippet and paste that HTML into the HTML area of the snippet. It may not be possible given privacy to your client or some other reason, but it's the next step to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output minus a few things, let me know if that's not enough. it appears the class refuses to change to "collapsible active" when clicked for only the odd rows. Thanks again for your patience and help!